# For loop over named folder to read each .txt filename and contents

Tags: php, file-io

The script below takes a named file that resides in the "myplugin" folder (the folder that the script itself resides in) and runs file_get_contents() on it to load the contents into memory, then does some preprocessing on the contents before finally inserting it as a post into the WordPress database via the wp_insert_post method.

```
$my_post3 = array();
$my_post3['post_title'] = 'Privacy Policy';
if(file_exists(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/pages/privacy_policy.txt'))
{
$my_privacy_policy = file_get_contents(ABSPATH.'/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/pages/privacy_policy.txt');
}
else
{
$my_privacy_policy = "";
}
$my_post3['post_content'] = addslashes($my_post3_replace);
$my_post3['post_type'] = 'page';
$my_post3['post_status'] = 'publish';
wp_insert_post($my_post3);
```

This method works pretty good. However, this method forces me to write a different routine for every file I want to use as the basis of a new page.

What I would like to do instead, is create a folder called "pages" and place my .txt files in that, then run a for loop on the contents of the folder, creating a new page for each file in the folder. I'd like to use the file name (minus the .txt extension) as the name of the page.

For example, the pages folder may have these files:

About Us.txt
Contact Us.txt

And the routine would result in the creation of two new pages in WordPress site, one called "About Us" containing the content found in that file. The other page would of course be "Contact Us" with the contents of that file.

In this way, I can just drop an unlimited number of named and prepopulated .txt files into that folder and when I activate my plugin, it creates those pages.

I just need some help with the for loop and how to reference the folder and files.

I will also have a folder called "posts", which will do the same for posts that this routine does for pages.

Thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Update based on @clientbucket answer:

```
DEFINE ('PAGES', './pages/');
$directory_pages = new DirectoryIterator(PAGES); 
foreach ($directory_pages as $files) {
    if ($files_pages->isFile()) {
        $file_name_page = $files_pages->getFilename();
        $my_page_content = file_get_contents(PAGES. $file_name_page);
        $my_page['post_content'] = addslashes($my_page_content);
        $my_page['post_title'] = $file_name_page;
        $my_page['post_type'] = 'page';
        $my_page['post_status'] = 'publish';
        wp_insert_post($my_page);
    }
}

DEFINE ('POSTS', './posts/');
$directory_posts = new DirectoryIterator(POSTS);
foreach ($directory_posts as $files_posts) {
    if ($files_posts->isFile()) {
        $file_name_post = $files_posts->getFilename();
        $my_post_content = file_get_contents(POSTS. $file_name_post);
        $my_post['post_content'] = addslashes($my_post_content);
        $my_post['post_title'] = $file_name_post;
        $my_post['post_type'] = 'post';
        $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
        stick_post($post_id);   
        }
}
```

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'DirectoryIterator::__construct(./pages/) [directoryiterator.--construct]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory' in C:\xampplite\htdocs\mytestsite\wp-content\plugins\myplugindirectory\myplugin.php:339

Line 339 is here > $directory_pages = new DirectoryIterator(PAGES);

Comment: I used `$filepart` to grab everything prior to the filetype ... you're not using it here so it's not necessary.

Comment: @philwinkle, I just have 2 questions left then. (1) How do I pull the name of the current text file (without the file extension) in the loop and (2) How do I obtain a reference to the file contents inside the loop?

Comment: To get the name of the current txt file with out the extension do this: $new_name = substr ($file_name, 0, -4); // Chop off the last four.

Comment: Chop off the last four is not an acceptable solution when someone names it .HTML ... you need to then chop off the last 5.... .text? ... rather use my solution to split at the period character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another way you could try.

```
DEFINE ('PAGES', './pages/'); //Define the directory path
$directory = new DirectoryIterator(PAGES); //Get all the contents in the directory 
foreach ($directory as $files) { //Check that the contents of the directory are each files  and then do what you want with them after you have the name of the file. 
    if ($files->isFile()) {
        $file_name = $files->getFilename();
        $my_page = file_get_contents(PAGES. $file_name); //Collect the content of the file.
    } else {
        //Insert nothing into the $my_privacy_policy variable.
    }
    echo $my_page; // Do what you want with the contents of the file.
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that, since this is a dynamic read, $my_privacy_policy should instead be $my_page (since, depending on the current file being read, it may be "About Us", "Contact Us" or whatever.

Comment: Yes. Your assumption is correct. It will be whatever the particular file is named. I will edit it based on your comment.

Comment: I think its going to work. It should, but I got a slight problem when I activated it. I'm going to post my code above if you can see the problem causing the error (if you don't mind, you've done enough already :-)

Comment: The error is because it is not finding the directory. Just make sure that it points to the pages directory like so: DEFINE ('PAGES', 'path/to/correct/directory/');

Comment: @clientbucket: I got it with ABSPATH.'path to folder'. Now just one thing left. How to remove .txt from the filename before its transferred as page title? My pages are title "About Us.txt" instead of "About Us"

Comment: $new_name = substr ($file_name, 0, -4); // Chop off the last four.

Comment: You should use `$files->getBasename('.txt')` to get the file name without the `.txt` extension.

Comment: It's not very polite to fish for attention on your answer on *another person's* answer... just saying.

Comment: @philwinkle Didn't mean to be impolite. My mistake. Just trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

From the PHP manual here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

They provide this solution for finding all text files in a directory:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "\n";
}
?>
```

Given this example, your actual request is to be able to create a file based on the name in another directory. I'll leave the hard work to you - but this is a simple implementation:

```
<?php
$source_dir = "/your/directory/with/textfiles";
$target_dir = "/directory/to/create/files/in";
foreach (glob($source_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "*.txt") as $filename) {
    $filepart = explode('.',$filename);
    file_put_contents($target_dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filepart[0] . ".php");
}
?>
```

Comment: @philwinkle,thanks for the example. One clarification is that I'm not creating any files (so no need for $target_dir). I'm just using my existing files in the plugin package to create database inserts that become virtual pages and posts in the WP database.

Comment: Okay - misunderstood you then... but at least the example gets you moving in the right direction!

Comment: @philwinkle: in your first example, where is the source folder reference? How would you specify the folder, for example, "pages" to be used as the source folder?

Comment: I believe that `glob` is relative to the document. So in that example, it was loading all text files in the same directory as the script itself. If you use the directory path structure like I did in the second example you have two options - relative path (e.g. `path/in/my/webroot`) or absolute path (e.g. `/var/www/mywordpressblog.com/public_html/`) And you have to concatenate them inside `glob` so that it search those specific directories. Does that make sense?

Comment: @philwinkle: I think I've got it. I updated the question with my interpretation of your code and I'm about to run a test against it.

Comment: How about the answer below. I have tested it and it works just fine.

Comment: @clientbucket: sorry, I didnt check it out yet. It looks like you've hardcoded the reference to privacy policy. The purpose of what I'm trying to do is have a dynamic loop over a folder and the filenames determine the name of the page or post. If that's what you meant, I'll take another look.

Comment: That is what I meant. It is actually not hard coded. I have collected the contents of the folder dynamically and gotten the name dynamically and also gotten the contents of the file dynamically as well. Everything is dynamic except for the definition of the folder path.